# CSS grid elements not aligned properly

Tags: css, css-grid

seems like an easy task which Im trying to get done since hours. I cant get my grid elements vertical aligned properly. Please take a look at the fiddle to get the idea. Maybe someone could help me with this issue.

HTML

```
 <section class="top">
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
 </section>

 <section class="bottom">
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
 </section>
```

CSS

```
 section {
   display: grid; 
   grid-template-rows:auto; 
   margin: 40px 0 0 0
 }

 section.top {
   grid-template-columns:2fr 1fr;
   grid-column-gap: 50px;
 }

 section.bottom {
   grid-template-columns:1fr 1fr 1fr;
   grid-column-gap: 50px;
 }

 section div {
   background:lightblue;
   height:400px
 }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ecj1wrae/

Comment: Do you mean the bottom two items must align in a column with the top item?

Comment: yes. And I need the section setup like this.

Comment: But you're dividing space using `fr` units, which applies only *free space* in the container. And the bottom section has 50px less free space than the top. So they cannot be aligned in this manner.

Comment: thanks for the claryfication. Can this question be deleted?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25088/how-can-i-delete-my-post-on-stack-overflow

Comment: and another thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, with some thinking and calculation this one here does the trick

CSS

```
section.top {
  grid-template-columns:calc(66% + 2vw) 34%;
  grid-column-gap: 2vw;
}

section.bottom {
  grid-template-columns:33% 33% 34%;
  grid-column-gap: 2vw;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ecj1wrae/3/

Comment: Good idea. Except the second column in `.top` should be just 34% (no need for `calc()`). Two reasons: (1) there is no column gap dividing the 34% item in `.bottom`, and (2) by subtracting 2vw you're shortening the item on the top (see the right margin).

Comment: Yeah. You´re right again. Thank you sir for your help and for commenting the other answers which did not really helped.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question... But I had a similar problem and I thought I'd share my solution for anyone else that needs some help.

This comment helped push me in the right direction

> But you're dividing space using fr units, which applies only free
> space in the container. And the bottom section has 50px less free
> space than the top. So they cannot be aligned in this manner

As the layout needs to consider the gaps between the columns I found it better to frame the problem as it needs to take up 2 columns of a 3 column layout instead of thinking it needs to take up 2fr of a 3fr layout.

Helpfully grid allows us to specify how many columns an element can span `grid-column: span 2;`

Using the html in the question we can use a span on the first div in the top section:

```css
section {
  display: grid; 
  margin: 40px 0 0 0;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(0, 1fr));
  grid-column-gap: 50px;
}

section.top div:first-child {
   grid-column: span 2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to do it with only 1 parent element, this may be a solution:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto;
  grid-row-gap: 50px;
  grid-column-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-areas: 
    'item1 item1 item1 item1 item2'
    'item3 item3 item4 item4 item5';
}
.wrapper > div {
  background: red;
  height: 400px;
}

.item1 {
  grid-area: item1;
}
.item2 {
  grid-area: item2;
}
.item3 {
  grid-area: item3;
}
.item4 {
  grid-area: item4;
}
.item5 {
  grid-area: item5;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item1"></div>
  <div class="item2"></div>
  <div class="item3"></div>
  <div class="item4"></div>
  <div class="item5"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Says in the comments to the question that HTML structure is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

A really simple solution is change the `grid-column-gap` by `margin` (if having space on the sides is not a problem):

HTML

```
<section class="top">
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
</section>

<section class="bottom">
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
</section>
```

CSS

```
section {
   display: grid; 
   grid-template-rows:auto; 
   margin: 4px 0 0 0
 }

 section.top {
   grid-template-columns:2fr 1fr;
 }

 section.bottom {
   grid-template-columns:1fr 1fr 1fr;
 }

 section div { 
   background:lightblue;
   height:400px;
   margin: 5px;
 }
```

https://codepen.io/fillsanches/pen/oNEpKWN